# Minimum hamming distance between two sets of binaries

Tags: linear-algebra

How does the fact that the hamming distance between any two vector elements of Z mod 2 of set V equal to the distance between these two vectors minus the zero vector (dist(x,y) = dist(x-y, e) where e is a zero vector) justify the fact that the minimum hamming distance between x and y is also the difference between any element of set V and the zero vector?

Comment: It doesn't. Unless $V$ is closed under subtraction of vectors. Which (modulo two) is equivalent to saying that it is closed under addition. In a coding theoretical context the property of "closed under addition" holds if and only if $V$ is a *linear* code. The result about minimum Hamming distances may hold for a given non-linear code also, but usually it doesn't.